# Noise reduction in ECL logic gates

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, bipolar

[image]

In this ECL circuit, how he got the equivalent circuit for the noise voltage and what is the meaning of hib4 in the equivalent circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IThe equivalent circuit for the noise source by itself is found by zeroing out all of the other voltage sources (principle of superposition).

Consider how R<sub>C2</sub> and Q4 are connected. The collector of Q2 can be ignored because its effective impedance is much larger than R<sub>C2</sub>. The effective resistance of this combination (h<sub>ib4</sub>) is R<sub>C2</sub> divided by the current gain (β) of Q4. For example, if the β is 100, the effective resistance is 2.45 Ω.

β is not a tightly controlled parameter, but if we can assume that its minimum value is 50, then the maximum equivalent resistance will be about 4.9 Ω, giving a minimum attenuation of 10:1 at the output terminal.

Note that the diagram is a bit confusing, because they reversed the polarity of V<sub>n2</sub> between the two circuits.